# Quicksort out of bounds (Kotlin)

Tags: kotlin, quicksort

I'm trying to implement quicksort in Kotlin.

I keep getting outofboundserror, but I just can't figure out why.

Below is my code:

```
fun quicksort(arr: MutableList<Int>) {
    quicksortHelper(arr, 0, arr.size + 1)
}

fun quicksortHelper(arr: MutableList<Int>, low: Int, high: Int) {
    if (low < high) {
        val partitionIdx = partition(arr, low, high)
        quicksortHelper(arr, low, partitionIdx)
        quicksortHelper(arr, partitionIdx + 1, high)
    }
}

fun partition (arr: MutableList<Int>, low: Int, high: Int): Int {
    val pivot = arr[low]
    var i= low
    var j = high
    while (i < j) {
        do {
            i++
        } while (arr[i] <= pivot)
        do {
            j--
        } while (arr[j] > pivot)
        if (i < j) {
            val temp = arr[i]
            arr[i] = arr[j]
            arr[j] = temp
        }
    }
    val temp = arr[low]
    arr[low] = arr[j]
    arr[j] = temp

    return j
}
```

Comment: It could help if you could add the full stack trace error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `quicksort`, you likely want to start with a high of `arr.size - 1`. That is:

```
fun quicksort(arr: MutableList<Int>) {
    quicksortHelper(arr, 0, arr.size - 1)
}
```

Other than that, it looks like you have some issues with your pivoting method and some inconsistencies in your indexing. You want to start with `i = low - 1` and `j = high + 1` or else you would be skipping the first and last elements of your array. Adding the following changes to your `partition` function in addition to the change above should fix your issue:

```
fun partition (arr: MutableList<Int>, low: Int, high: Int): Int {
    val pivot = arr[(high + low) / 2] // pivot at the middle element instead of `low`
    var i = low - 1
    var j = high + 1
    while (i < j) {
        do {
            i++
        } while (arr[i] < pivot)
        do {
            j--
        } while (arr[j] > pivot)
        if (i < j) {
            val temp = arr[i]
            arr[i] = arr[j]
            arr[j] = temp
        }
    }
    val temp = arr[low]
    arr[low] = arr[j]
    arr[j] = temp

    return j
}
```

For more details, see the 'Hoarse Partition Scheme' pseudocode on the [wikipedia quicksort page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort).